# Communicate with an AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm running a socket client in my `AsyncTask`. I need to find a way to call send externally. Ex: `socketClient.send(msg);` `SocketClient` is defined in a `service`. Send will be called when the UI sends a `broadcast` and the `service receives` it. So far all my attempts have caused the app to crash.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class SocketClient extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private Socket socket = null;
    private BufferedReader in = null;
    private PrintWriter out = null;
    private boolean connected;

    String devID;

    public SocketClient(String ip, int port, String devID){
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.devID = devID;

        connected = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
        try{
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            socket = null;
        }

        try{
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

            send(new SocketMessage("ident", "sdas", "", ""));

            while(connected) {
                SocketMessage msg = new SocketMessage(in.readLine());
                handle(msg);
            }

            //clean up
            out.println(new SocketMessage("quit", "","", ""));
            out.flush();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                connected = false;
                out.close();
                in.close();
                socket.close();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void handle(SocketMessage msg){

    }

    public synchronized void send(SocketMessage msg){
        out.println(msg.getJSON());
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this        ' SocketClient  socketClient  = new SocketClient(ip, 
                                                                   port,devID);                       
                      socketClient .execute();   '

Comment: You said your app crashes. what is the error shown in trace log ?

Comment: I would suggest using [Handlers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `AsyncTask` is not designed for long running processes. In that case you are better of using a `Thread`. See the developer guide for [Connecting Techniques](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectionTechniques).

Answer (score 0):

Try an event bus like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) from Square or [Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) from Green Robot. IPC is difficult in Android and these libraries abstract it to make it less painful to work with.